# When *should* old style numbers be used?

Tags: typography, oldstylenums

> Not sure if this is too subjective but here goes...

Using fonts like [`newpx`](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/newpx/) and [`ebgaramond`](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/ebgaramond/), the old style figures options seem to affect all figures (as in numbers) in the document.
Is this good typography? If not, is there any guidance on when and how to apply `\liningnums` to some elements?

In the example below we have:
chapter & section numbers, numeric citations, a footnote, inline math*, an equation*, enumeration, figure number, and inline numbers.
I'd appreciate any guidance about whether old style figures should / not be used in any of these, though I take it math (*) probably should always be lining (non-old style) figures.

---

[image: example]

Comment: A lot is a matter of style and personal preference. One question is if you are writing a novel or a scientific publication. (I am the last person to frown upon fancy typesetting, but oldstyle figures in a math thesis scratch the wrong itch!) I think that reading up Tschichold, Bringhurst, Gill, Tufte, and so on (`texdoc memoir` at least!), might help. In the end it is personal preference married with the traditions of the field.

Comment: Another point in "choosing numbers" is lining vs. "tabular", equispaced numbers (present in Minion, for example). TOC and tables might want the ones with all equal spacing. Especially single / few digits in text look better when proportional. Now, throw in the oldstyle...

Comment: Although the two styles of numerals were Euler vs. Concrete Roman, Knuth addressed the necessary mechanism in an article for TUGboat: ["Typesetting Concrete Mathematics"](https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb10-1/tb23knut.pdf).  It's certainly personal preference, but the discussion about how to maintain consistency may be of interest.